# Sprint boot jpa, return custom class from query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have some custom query ie:

```
@Query("SELECT cells.res, event.eventDate, count(*) FROM ABC abc " +
            "JOIN abc.data as cells " +
            "JOIN cells.samples as samples " +
            "JOIN samples.ev as event " +
            "WHERE event.id IN :ids "+
            "GROUP BY event.id, samples.id")

    Set<XYZProjection> findXYZBySubjectId(List<Long> ids);
```

( some data changed as I dont want ot paste real query ;) )

and Ive created XYZProjection class, with 3 fields inside.

```
public class XYZProjection implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long positive;
    private LocalDate eventDate;
    private Long count;
    public SubjectSamplesProjection(Long res, LocalDate date, Long count) {
        this.res = res;
        this.date = eventDate;
        this.count = count;
    }
    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public Long getRes() {
        return res;
    }
}
```

But then I get `ConverterNotFoundException` how can I fix that ?

( Idea is to create a class, dont want trigger creating a table, and this class will return from this query )

thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the LocalDate causes the issue here, not the whole of XYZProjection. Perhaps try to omit that field and try again so you know for sure

Answer (score 0):

How findXYZBySubjectId() will work where there is no field called "subjectId" is  available  in POJO.
And also your query is not clear.

please refer the link for more information:---

[enter link description here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa)